# Changing location of the image using '<img src>'

Tags: html, perl

I am using the below command to get the png image into my html page.

```perl
print count_out '<img src="./mydata.png">';
```

I am also writing out a table to my html page. The problem is this image appears on top and then below is the table.
I need table on top and then image below.

Below is the part were i am printing the table:

```perl
print count_out "<HTML>";
print count_out "<head>";
print count_out "</head>";
print count_out "<table border='1' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' width='50%' height='1%'>";
while (<F>) {
    chomp;
    my @list = split(/,/);
    my $design = $list[0];
    my $bto_date = $list[1];
    my $die_size = $list[2];
    my $technology = $list[3];
    my $transistor_count = $list[4];

print count_out "<tr>";
print count_out "<TD padding-left: 10pxpadding-right: 10pxwidth='90px'bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><font size='2'>$design</TD>";
print count_out "<TD padding-left: 10pxpadding-right: 10pxwidth='90px'bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><font size='2'>$bto_date</TD>";
print count_out "<TD padding-left: 10pxpadding-right: 10pxwidth='90px'bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><font size='2'>$die_size</TD>";
print count_out "<TD padding-left: 10pxpadding-right: 10pxwidth='90px'bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><font size='2'>$technology</TD>";
print count_out "<TD padding-left: 10pxpadding-right: 10pxwidth='90px'bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><font size='2'>$transistor_count</TD>";
print count_out "</tr>";
```

Comment: There is no `</table>` printed, i.e. the table is never closed. This might explain why the position of the image is messed up - although you don't shown where exactly this img related print statement is done in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You do not close the  tag.

```
print count_out "</table>";
```

is missing at least.

Answer (score 0):

thanks
adding the below line worked for me

```
print count_out "</table>";
```

also when i open the html ..i see the table but the image does not show up .. i have click the refresh 8-10 times ..then it shows up ..why is that

Comment: depending on your browser, this might just be caching. Try clearing the browser cache and then running the script.

Comment: This is not an answer instead missed out issues.